# TYPO3 8.7.13 - getArguments() return no response

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

\Templates\Snippets\Search.html

```
<f:form id="snippetSearchForm"
        action="search"
        controller="Snippets"
        extensionName="snippet_highlight_syntax"
        pluginName="feshs"
        name="searchSnippets"
        method="POST"
        pageType="5513">
    <f:form.textfield class="form-control" property="searchWords"/>
    <f:form.submit id="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
</f:form>
```

SnippetsController.php

```
public function searchAction()
    {
        $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($arguments);
    }
```

ajax.js

```
$("#snippetSearchForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var action = form.attr("action"),
        method = form.attr("method"),
        data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function () {
        ( "div.tx-feshs" ).replaceWith("errorMessage");
    }).always(function () {

    });
});
```

Request URL

```
index.php?id=148&type=5513&tx_snippet_highlight_syntax_feshs[action]=search&tx_snippet_highlight_syntax_feshs[controller]=Snippets&cHash=4662b6b5a3fa0dc4e590e8d5c90fa
```

I can't solve this problem with `getArguments()`. The response and console.log are (empty). Seems like I'm missing something but I can't pinpoint where :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few common errors in your code and most of them has already been mentioned here, but please allow me to sum up.

### Extension key/name

First, a lot of people confuses *extension name* with *extension key*. The directory name of your extension is your *extension key*, in this case `snippet_highlight_syntax`. The *extension key* is used all over TYPO3 as the unique identifier of your extension. With Extbase a new convention did come along called *extension name* to satisfy [PSR2 coding convention](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) and is primarily used in Extbase context. The *extension name* is a upper camel case edition of your *extension key*.

[ExtbaseFluidBook: CodingGuidelines](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/a-CodingGuidelines/Index.html) - *It´s a bid old but still valid*

> The name of the extension in UpperCamelCase. For example, if the extension-key is blog_example, then this part of the classname is BlogExample.

Extension key: `snippet_highlight_syntax`
Extension name: `SnippetHighlightSyntax`

Be aware of what the TYPO3/Extbase framework asks for, key or name - it will help you a lot.

---

### Plugin name

You have also declared a plugin named `feshs`. According to the DocBlock documentation of both `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::(configure|register)Plugin()` methods it should, as with the extension name, be in upper camel case format like `Feshs`. It´s not well documented and I do not think it has any negative impacted on your application jet but now you knows and has a change to future proof your application by correcting it.

```
/**
 * ...
 *
 * @param string $extensionName The extension name (in UpperCamelCase) or the extension key (in lower_underscore)
 * @param string $pluginName must be a unique id for your plugin in UpperCamelCase (the string length of the extension key added to the length of the plugin name should be less than 32!)
 * @param array $controllerActions is an array of allowed combinations of controller and action stored in an array (controller name as key and a comma separated list of action names as value, the first controller and its first action is chosen as default)
 * @param array $nonCacheableControllerActions is an optional array of controller name and  action names which should not be cached (array as defined in $controllerActions)
 * @param string $pluginType either \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_PLUGIN (default) or \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public static function configurePlugin($extensionName, $pluginName, array $controllerActions, array $nonCacheableControllerActions = [], $pluginType = self::PLUGIN_TYPE_PLUGIN)
```

---

### Plugin signature

Together with your extension name it will form a plugin signature called `snippethighlightsyntax_feshs`. This signature is the valued stored in the `tt_content` database table as `list_type` or `ctype` depending of the plugin configuration.

The plugin signature is further used in TypoScript and GET/POST arguments prefixed with `tx_`. In your case `tx_snippethighlightsyntax_feshs`.

---

## Fluid & Extbase forms

In your form snippet you have declared a element `<f:form:textfield />` with the `property` tag. The `property` tag is only used together with the `object` and `objectName` tags on the `<f:form />` element and is used to bind values to this objects properties (autofill, validation result etc.).

See `\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Form\AbstractFormFieldViewHelper::initializeArguments`.

> Name of Object Property. If used in conjunction with `<f:form object="..."`>, "name" and "value" properties will be ignored.

In your case you should properly just use `name` in stead of `property`.

Your updated form should look something like below:

```
<f:form id="snippetSearchForm"
        action="search"
        controller="Snippets"
        extensionName="SnippetHighlightSyntax"
        pluginName="Feshs"
        method="POST"
        pageType="5513">
    <f:form.textfield class="form-control" name="searchWords"/>
    <f:form.submit id="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
</f:form>
```

---

### Controller arguments

You should declare your arguments as controller arguments.

```
/**
 * @param string $searchWords
 */
public function searchAction(string $searchWords = null)
{
    if (is_string($searchWords)) {
        // TODO: Do something here...
    }
}
```

Note how I have given the argument a default value. This should suppress the error `Required argument "searchWords" is not set for...` you are getting.

---

This was a long write up. Hopes it helps your or some others.

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sum up. It will help me explain my procedures during my exam next week :D

Answer (score 0):

`$this->request->getArguments()` will only return field value arguments that are prefixed with the extensions / plugins identifier like tx_anything_pi1[anything]
Please checkout if the "name"-tag of the fields is correct. Maybe those tags are wrong because you are reffering to a "property" of an object in your textfield but there is no object bound to your f:form tag.

Since the response should at least return the HTML of an empty debug, maybe something is wrong with your action. Can you call it in the browser?

Comment: That's where I was looking, I'll search for the `object` tag and verify the `name` too.

Comment: The action is working, I've send `$this->view->assign('test', 'searchAction test');` and it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your extension-key (=foldername) is "snippet_highlight_syntax" the parameter for URLs is usually like this:

```
tx_snippethighlightsyntax_feshs
```

That means all underscores of the extension-key are removed.
Probably it's possible to make it different, but that's not standard.
Therefore `$this->request->getArguments()` never returns anything.
You've to adjust the parameters in the url like this:

```
index.php?id=148&type=5513&tx_snippethighlightsyntax_feshs[action]=search&tx_snippethighlightsyntax_feshs[controller]=Snippets&cHash=4662b6b5a3fa0dc4e590e8d5c90fa
```

In the TypoScript-Object-Browser you should find your plugin with that name:

```
plugin.tx_snippethighlightsyntax_feshs
```

Comment: The extension's folder name is "_snippet_highlight_syntax_" so I've wrote `extensionName="snippet_highlight_syntax"`. Tried to change it with no underscore give the same result.

Comment: it's not about that, it's about the parameters in your URL.
Just look in the produced "name"-attibutes in your input-fields in the HTML-code how they are noted. [EDIT:] Saw you've a textfield, so look there

Comment: The `extensionName` was rename with `snippethighlightsyntax` so that the name attributes are `name="tx_snippethighlightsyntax_feshs[__referrer]`

Seems like it ?

Comment: Should be, you can control in TypoScript-Object-Browser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `name` attribute instead of `property` in `<f:form.textfield>` tag.

Then you need to register argument as follows

> public function searchAction(**string $searchWords**)

Furthermore PHP docblock must contain the parameter as `@param string $searchWords`. After clearing all caches in the Install Tool you should get your arguments.

Comment: Changing `property` to `name` gave me `tx_snippethighlightsyntax_feshs[searchWords]: my_search_input` but if I try to register **$searchWords** in my controller:

`Required argument \"searchWords\" is not set for SnippetHighlightSyntax\\SnippetHighlightSyntax\\Controller\\SnippetsController->search`

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I've sent the extension to test on another computer and it's working.

I've cleared all the caches, disabled/enabled, and so on. Seems like my environment is at fault.

Thanks to all of you for the help !